# Wordpress: Use Sub Domain for all Posts / Not Pages

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a custom WordPress theme and have a question if I can about forcing posts pages to a subdomain.

I'm using Pages, along with ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) to develop the theme (in case that's relevant). I have a couple page templates, one for the homepage, and one for inner pages. I've told Wordpress to use the Page "News" (/news) as the index for the blog/posts pages.

So we're using `something.com`, and we'd like to have `blog.something.com` utilize the `/news` content, and, have all that content maintain the subdomain URL while browsing the content of the post(s).

Is this is a multi-site thing? Can it be done with DNS alone?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to pull something off with a CNAME record, but this is not really possible without utilizing a Network install. Have one WordPress site for the news, another for the page content.

Comment: Not sure I understand completely though how Network sites would function. Would I have to have duplicated headers and footers (custom theme per) with hard-coded URLs to navigate back and forth between the two sites?

Comment: @David Yes. They would be two distinct sites. You could technically have a sub directory in your current WP install with another WP install for the blog - but you're almost doing the same thing as a Multisite. There's not really a good way to have a subdomain for just the blog without using two separate installs.

Comment: Welp... that's a bummer, but I get it. Thanks to everyone.